# When did a specific database come online?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I determine when the state of a specific database switched to online?

Background: I want to determine how long the database is in use to find out how reliable `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` currently is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @SQLLearner specificed in his answer, the easiest way without auditing in place or an XE session running would be to just look in the SQL Server Log.  The below code will get the most recent startup of a particular database (using `YourDatabaseName` in this example, but obviously change it for your environment):

```
create table #error_log
(
    LogDate datetime not null,
    ProcessInfo nvarchar(128) not null,
    Text nvarchar(512) not null
)
go

insert into #error_log
exec xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Starting', N'YourDatabaseName'
go

select top 1
    LogDate,
    Text
from #error_log
order by LogDate desc
```

As per @usr's comment an [Connect link](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/684695/getting-errors-when-using-xp-readerrorlog-in-a-loop-when-using-filter-parameters-causes-error), in SQL Server 2012 Unicode parameters are required.

Comment: I received a "severe error" in Denali because this script did not use unicode strings. I edited this post. Reference: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/684695/getting-errors-when-using-xp-readerrorlog-in-a-loop-when-using-filter-parameters-causes-error

Comment: @usr Looks like you are correct.  I originally wrote the code with SQL Server 2008 R2, and testing it on 2012 you are correct.  Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 1):

You can look into sys.dm_os_sys_info DMV and sqlserver_start_time to determine when SQL Server service was started. This was also start point for sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats DMV.

If you want to find out when specific database was bought onine, you need to look into SQL Server ErrorLog for something like "Starting up Database"

Comment: Database online and SQL-service running are not the same thing. Am I missing something?

Comment: I agree with the above comment. The OP is looking for when a database came online, and that doesn't necessarily mean when SQL Server was started.

Comment: I understand, but AFAIK no easy way to find out.  OP: Look into SQL Server ErrorLog when database was bought ONLINE.